# Best way to migrate domain to new IP

Tags: migration, domain-name, a-record

I have a website that has around 50-70k daily traffic. I am mostly interested in with software and a little bit hardware.

I would like to hear professionals thought about migration.

I am going to switch my ISP, since I am switching my ISP I will have to change my servers IP. But I want migration to be smooth, since I -unexpectedly- got high traffic.

It is okay to point 2 IP address to the same domain?

```
Old IP -> example.com
New IP -> example.com
```

Then after 72 hours, I will remove the old IP. Is this a good solution for migration or would you suggest another method for migration?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: An IP is an Internet Protocol, and there are only two: IPv4 and IPv6. I think you mean IP address. There are many things IP, e.g. IP route. If you mean IP address, you should really specify what you mean, e.g. IPv4 address. The IETF has a current working group to sunset IPv4: "_The term 'IP,' without address family specified, is assumed to mean 'IPv6.'_"

Comment: My website is hosted on a DHCP IP address, if you set a low ttl, id expect less than one hour downtime, you can also tell people ahead of time of possible down time and make the change on like monday 1am

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before you end your relationship with your current provider set the TTL value for example.com to a low value e.g. 500 seconds. Note that this change will tale at least the original TTL to be 'seen' across the internet. Migrate everything to your new provider and ensure that it is up-to-date and working correctly. When you are ready to switch change the DNS entry for example.com to point to the new IP address. This will be 'seen' by most quite quickly as you set the TTL to 500 earlier but there will likely be outliers. On your old server arrange to make it read only or perhaps have it reverse proxy to the new server.

Comment: Definitely reduce the TTL, but (despite the fact it breaks the rules) anything shorter than 3 hours will be treated as 3 hours by a lot of DNS servers. I've not run such an exercise for a few years, but the last time I was still seeing (small amounts) of traffic on the old IP after 24 hours.

Comment: Some resolvers may muck with the TTL indeed, but there are not hard rules. Amazon ones clamp at 1 hours for example. Resolvers could shorten the delay not extend it.

Comment: Before changing the TTL you need to shorten the refresh parameter too or have full control of all nameservers, otherwise slaves will not get the new information fast (depends on how all nameservers are managed, if they use DNS UPDATE messages, etc...)